# How to retrieve the data corresponding to the link clicked in Django

Tags: html, django, ajax, django-templates

I have a database with book = {Id, title, rating, page_count, author}

In home.html I'm displaying the Title as a link and when the user clicks it should redirect to a page with all the details.

home.html

```html
{% for book in books %}
      <a href= "buy.html"> {{ book.Title }} </a>
      <p> Rated - {{ book.Rating }}</p>
      <p> {{ book.Authors }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Now when the user clicks on the Title it redirects to a new page buy.html and I want to display the complete details stored in my database.

Can someone assist me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up another url, view and template to handle the product page. For example:
The your template could look like this:

```
<h1> {{ book.Title }} </h1>
... other details....
```

The your view could look like this:

```
def book_view(request, book_id):
    book = ... get the book by id...
    return render(request, 'buy.html',{'book':book})
```

The url could look like this:

```
path('book/<book_id>', book_view, name='book-page')
```

You would link the product by changing the href in your code from `href= "buy.html`" to `href= "{% url 'book-page' %}"`.

I suggest you read [this](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/) to catch up on some of the basics before you continue.